# SQL Server - Derived column using its own previous value from the second row on

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a derived column, ColumnC, in SQL Server. The rule is the first row of ColumnC is the product of ColumnA and ColumnB. The following rows are the product of the previous row in ColumnC ordered by Year times ColumnA * ColumnC.

```
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
| **Year**  |        **ColumnA**       |      **ColumnB**       |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2020     |        0.987441          |        0.001039        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2021     |        0.975952          |        0.001117        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2022     |        0.965471          |        0.001206        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2023     |        0.955950          |        0.001293        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2024     |        0.947347          |        0.001387        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2025     |        0.939604          |        0.001488        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2026     |        0.933461          |        0.001596        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2027     |        0.922700          |        0.001710        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2028     |        0.914439          |        0.001959        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  2029     |        0.900277          |        0.002134        |
+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------+
```

Just to keep the example simple I simplified the calculations and the table, therefore, I need the column tobe computed as described.

Obeying the following algorithm is essential for me: The first row of ColumnC is the product of ColumnA abd ColumnB, the following rows, from the second row on, use the previous row of ColumnC ordered by Year times ColumnB times ColumnC.

My biggest problem, that got me stuck, is that I don't know how toget the previous value of ColumnC. I cannot use `LAG` because the column doesn't exist yet.

```
SELECT
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    /* First row okay. But the following rows should 
     use the previous value of ColumnC times ColumnA times ColumnB
     that is ColumnC(Year-1) * ColumnA * ColumnB
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Year) = 1 THEN
        ColumnA * ColumnB
    ELSE
        LAG(ColumnC) OVER (ORDER BY Year) * ColumnA * ColumnB
    END AS ColumnC
    */
    (ColumnA * ColumnB) AS ColumnC
FROM TableA
```

This won't work:

```
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Year ASC) = 1 THEN
    ColumnA * ColumnB
ELSE
    LAG(ColumnC) OVER (ORDER BY Year ASC) * ColumnA * ColumnB
END AS ColumnC
```

Please, help me to understand my problem.

> [**Useless SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b8227/2)

Calculation of the first row from ColumnC:

[image]

Calculation from the second row on from ColumnC:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! I edited the question and added the the results and examples in Google Sheets. I'll test your solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers get really small really fast, but this does what you describe:

```
select a.*, 
       columna * columnb,
       exp(sum(log(columna * columnb)) over (order by year))
from tableA a
```

Comment: Hi, Mr. Linoff! Thank you for your answer. I'm gonna implement a derivation of it using exponentials. That will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for based on the information provided.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TableA

CREATE TABLE #TableA (
    [Year] INT,
    ColumnA DECIMAL(8, 6),
    ColumnB DECIMAL(8, 6)
)

INSERT INTO #TableA (
  [Year],
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB
)
VALUES
    (2020, 0.987441, 0.001039),
    (2021, 0.975952, 0.001117),
    (2022, 0.965471, 0.001206),
    (2023, 0.955950, 0.001293),
    (2024, 0.947347, 0.001387),
    (2025, 0.939604, 0.001488),
    (2026, 0.933461, 0.001596),
    (2027, 0.922700, 0.001710),
    (2028, 0.914439, 0.001959),
    (2029, 0.900277, 0.002134);

    SELECT *, CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Year ASC) = 1 THEN ColumnA * ColumnB
              ELSE LAG(ColumnB) OVER (ORDER BY Year ASC) * ColumnA * ColumnB
               END AS ColumnC
      FROM #TableA
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your quick answer, but I think that Mr. Linoff's thought on exponentials will help me more effectivelly.